# How do you run an executable from within an air application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a program (C++ program which interacts directly with drivers for attached hardware) which I need to run from within an air application.  I have been looking around, but some of the information is 4 years old saying AS2 will allow this (I am using AS3), and the rest refers to using fscommand and says it has to be in a folder with that name, but not where that folder should be.

I would prefer to have the AIR application interact with the .exe, but if possible/necessary I could have it interact directly with the .dll instead.

Comment: To run an exe, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345184/possible-to-disable-windows-start-menu-while-air-app-is-running/27347274#27347274). For dlls, I don't know.

Comment: You can use Native Process. See this article from Adobe: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922487/1457439

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe AIR to execute program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672021/adobe-air-to-execute-program)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to call a native DLL from Adobe AIR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708648/is-it-possible-to-call-a-native-dll-from-adobe-air)